# Focusing on a subgoal

Tags: isabelle

Having worked with Coq before, I'm used to its system of "focusing" and "unfocusing" goals, so you can work with one goal at a time.

Does a similar system exists in Isabelle?

As an example, this code:

```
theory Scratch
  imports Main
begin

theorem add_0: "n+0 = (n::nat)"
  apply(induction n)
```

Generates a proof state with 2 subgoals:

```
proof (prove)
goal (2 subgoals):
 1. 0 + 0 = 0
 2. ⋀n. n + 0 = n ⟹
         Suc n + 0 = Suc n
```

If I use `apply(auto)`, both of them are solved. Let's suppose however that I want to work only on goal 1, is it possible to "focus" on it? If not, how may I apply `auto` to only one (or some) of the subgoals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathias and Manuel mentioned the Isar style as the preferred way to focus on subgoals. Here is an example of how that could look like:

```
theorem add_0: "n+0 = (n::nat)"
proof (induction n)
  case 0 ― ‹Focus on induction base subgoal here›
  show "0 + 0 = (0::nat)" 
    by (rule plus_nat.add_0)
next
  case (Suc n) ― ‹Focus on induction step subgoal here›
  show "Suc n + 0 = Suc n"
  proof (subst plus_nat.add_Suc)
    show "Suc (n + 0) = Suc n"
      by (subst Suc.IH) (rule refl)
  qed
qed
```

Or implicitly, without naming cases:

```
theorem add_0: "n+0 = (n::nat)"
proof (induction n)
  show "0 + 0 = (0::nat)" 
    by (rule plus_nat.add_0)
next
  fix n :: nat
  assume IH: "n + 0 = n"
  show "Suc n + 0 = Suc n"
  proof (subst plus_nat.add_Suc)
    show "Suc (n + 0) = Suc n"
      by (subst IH) (rule refl)
  qed
qed
```

Comment: I am (genuinely) curious whether `(subst IH) (rule refl)` considered to be a good style and encouraged in this scenario. I thought that this pattern is reserved, primarily, for terminal steps using some non-trivial automation provided by methods like `auto`. To be clear, I am aware of the factual differences (e.g. backtracking) between the behavior of (e.g.) structural composition and `by () ()` pattern.

Comment: Good question. I don't know of a style guide that covers this. I prefer the variant without backtracking, because it is less complex (rule of least power).

Comment: I believe that backtracking can only be prevented in all situations either through the use of `apply (...) by (...)` or `apply(...) apply(...) done`. To the best of my knowledge `by (..., ...)` and `by () ()` can both backtrack (e.g., see https://lists.cam.ac.uk/mailman/htdig/cl-isabelle-users/2020-February/msg00062.html). I guess, when backtracking is not needed and there are no chained facts, there is no 'best solution' when it comes to style. So, the form that you used here makes sense.

Comment: You're right. The reference manual is wrong, where it states that `by m1 m2` is short for `proof m1 qed m2`, which does not use backtracking. So I guess it's mostly about whether m2 uses the "facts" or not.

Comment: Sorry, the reference manual is not wrong: http://phdcomics.com/comics/archive/phd092815s.gif :). Either way, all of this is getting slightly off-topic. Maybe these comments ought to be deleted? Feel free to delete yours, and I will follow.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use Isar (which probably is better for readability), you can use `subgoal` to focus on the goal:

```
theorem add_0: "n+0 = (n::nat)"
  apply(induction n)
  subgoal by auto
  subgoal by auto
```

or the brackets:

```
apply auto[]
```

to focus `auto` on the first goal only.

The main difference is that `subgoal` makes it impossible to instantiate schematic variables.

Comment: Is it possible to specify a specific subgoal to focus on? Focusing on *2* first instead of *1*, for example.

Comment: `defer` (to prove the first goal last) and `prefer n` (to move the n-th goal to the first position).

Comment: Note that, in my opinion, using `defer` and `prefer` is discouraged. ‘apply’-style proofs in general are somewhat discouraged (albeit to a lesser degree than `defer`/`prefer`). These all do have their place, but for most applications, Isar proofs are cleaner, more readable, and more maintainable.

Comment: I for one tend to break up proofs into single steps in Isar, where the proof of each step looks somethling like `by (rule foo) (auto simp: …)` or `by (intro foo) (auto simp: …)` or `by (subst foo) (auto simp: …)`. But of course, different people have different styles. I think it is fair to say though that relying heavily on the automation to solve trivial side conditions is very idiomatic for Isabelle.

Comment: @ManuelEberl I have absolutely no idea how to write refinement proofs (Peter Lammich style) in Isar. In any other case Isar is clearly nicer.

Comment: Indeed, refinement proofs are one example where apply-style may be justified. But most Isabelle proofs are not like that, especially not those by beginners.